# Codeigniter Array to Database with foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm trying to store details about uploaded files in the DB.

Presently details of single uploaded files go into an array. I have no idea on how I should write this info into the DB.

I think this must be done using a foreach loop with the array but I'm not sure how to do this.

Please advise.

My model looks like this:

```
class download_model extends CI_Model {

    //
    // Add file
    public function add() {
        $new_file = array(
            'file_author_id'            =>  $this->profil_model->get_user_id(),
            'file_author_name'          =>  $this->profil_model->get_firstname().' '.$this->profil_model->get_lastname(),
            'file_name'                 =>  $this->input->post('file_name'), <-- IN THIS I MUST RUN LOOP TO SEND MULTIPLE VALUES- I HAVE NO IDEA HOW I CAN DO THIS :(
        );
        $this->db->insert('download', $new_file);
    }
}
```

This is my upload file(s) result:

```
Array
(
    [pageTitle] => Multiple file upload
    [uploads] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file_name] => MY_FILE_NAME.txt
                    [file_type] => text/plain
                    [file_path] => DIR
                    [full_path] => DIR/MY_FILE_NAME.txt
                    [raw_name] => MY_FILE_NAME
                    [orig_name] => MY_FILE_NAME.txt
                    [client_name] => MY_FILE_NAME.txt
                    [file_ext] => .txt
                    [file_size] => 0.98
                    [is_image] => 
                    [image_width] => 
                    [image_height] => 
                    [image_type] => 
                    [image_size_str] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file_name] => MY_FILE_NAME_2.txt
                    [file_type] => text/plain
                    [file_path] => DIR
                    [full_path] => MY_FILE_NAME_2.txt
                    [raw_name] => MY_FILE_NAME_2
                    [orig_name] => MY_FILE_NAME_2.txt
                    [client_name] => MY_FILE_NAME_2.txt
                    [file_ext] => .txt
                    [file_size] => 0.98
                    [is_image] => 
                    [image_width] => 
                    [image_height] => 
                    [image_type] => 
                    [image_size_str] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Please, help me or do anything how I can do this :( It's possible to do :( ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change your code a bit.

You model should look like this:

```
public function add($userId, $authorName, $fileName) {
    $new_file = array(
        'file_author_id'            =>  $userId,
        'file_author_name'          =>  $authorName,
        'file_name'                 =>  $fileName,
    );

    return $this->db->insert('download', $new_file);
}
```

And in your Controller you should do the needed foreach like this:

```
public function upload() {
    //GETTING YOUR DATA RIGHT HERE

    $userId     = $this->profil_model->get_user_id();
    $authorName = $this->profil_model->get_firstname().' '.$this->profil_model->get_lastname();

    foreach ($uploads as $upload) {
        $this->model_name->add($userId, $authorName, $upload['file_name']);
    }
}
```

Or if you want 1 row with all uploaded files in that field, do this:

```
public function upload() {
    //GETTING YOUR DATA RIGHT HERE

    $userId       = $this->profil_model->get_user_id();
    $authorName   = $this->profil_model->get_firstname().' '.$this->profil_model->get_lastname();
    $fileString   = '';
    $countUploads = count($uploads);

    $i = 1;

    foreach ($uploads as $upload) {
        $fileString .= $upload['file_name']

        if ($i < $countUploads) {
            $fileString .= ',';
        }

        $i++;
    }

    $this->model_name->add($userId, $authorName, $fileString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very much simpler approach can be applied using insert_batch function

```
<?php
   public function add() {
    //prepare the array of data
    $insert = array_map(function($row){
       return array(
         'file_author_id'   => $this->profil_model->get_user_id(),
         'file_author_name'  =>  $this->profil_model->get_firstname().' '.$this->profil_model->get_lastname(),
         'file_name' => $row['file_name']
      );
    },$this->input->post('uploads'));
   $this->db->insert_batch('download', $insert);
  }
```